# Algorithm: path finding with variable path width

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

given a grid of paths with different width, how can i find a path which leads to the end point?

The path is going to be represented by a two dimentional array where 0 means cannot be walk on, 1 means it is walkable, 2 represents starting point and 3 represents end point. Consider the following example:

```
21111111100000
00000011000000
00001111111111
00001111100111
00001110000101
00001111100113
```

in the above example the width of a path varies from 1 to 3, and there exists many solutions which would lead to the end point. I want to find one path which leads to it and the path does not have to be the shortest one (should not be the longest one either). The width of each path is unknown which means the grid could be all "1"s except the starting and end point.

Edited: The path should not contain uneccessary "wasted" walk meaning that if a vertical path has width 2 the result should not just walk down the path and then take one step right then walk all the way up

Comment: Any shortest path algorithm would work, Dijkstras, Bellman-ford. What is the preference for the algorith, speed?

Comment: @Calum easy to implement is the top priority. The width and height of the grid should be less than 1000x1000 so i dont think speed would be a problem. I think some path algorithms would run into loops or take on uneccessary paths but i might be wrong

Comment: I would suggest using a depth first algorithm and recording where you have already been (probably use coordinates) that way you wont run into loops

Comment: @Calum in the example given, some algorithms would produce a path which would walk all the way right, then down, left, down, up, right, and then down, note that since the width of some paths is >1 so dfs would say no loop.

Comment: that would be one path but most depth first algorithms once they reach a dead end will back track and try a different route. You have to keep track of where you have been

Comment: I suggest finding a preexisting module you can utilise rather than writing the algorithm yourself if ease is your criteria

Comment: @Calum well that is not a dead end, when it reaches bottom it could choose to either go all the way right , or right one step and then all the way up. since none of the nodes have been visited so it is not a loop. Now that is a path i do not want.

Comment: true, but by keeping track of where you have already been you will stop yourself going in loops ie if i know i have already been to position and i end up there again i know i have made a loop and should back track

Comment: @Calum yea i understand what you mean. But in the example i just gave although it is not a direct loop it is still consider as a loop to me since it walked down a path and then walked back up. I do not want any loop. Especially when it is possible to be in an open area I do not want to have to walk the entire area with a small chance.

Comment: Does the width matter to you? That is, do you need to find the entire wide path or just a single strand of connected points?

Comment: @Calum: BFS is a lot better since it will find you the shortest path in a reasonable amount of time. Even better is to BFS from both ends until both searches hit a common point; in an `MxN` grid, you can guarantee that no more than `MN/4` points are touched even if all points are marked as walkable.

Comment: @rici no, path width does not matter. All i need is a single strand of connected points which does not contain direct or indirect loop

Comment: @Steve you keep on using the word "loop", but what you're describing isn't a loop. It's a trackback, a path that returns near where it was before (but not exactly). It would have to go to exactly the same spot to be a loop. All trackpath paths have the property that you can shortcut the "trackback" part. Therefore the surefire way to guarantee no trackbacks is to use a shortest path algorithm.

Comment: @rici BFS gives better-quality results, but it's arguably harder to write. The original question asked for any path (doesn't have to be shortest) using the simplest possible algo. Of course it's different if you want to take into account Steve's added requirement of a "no-trackback" path.

Comment: @redtuna: The only difference between BFS and DFS is that in DFS you use recursion and in BFS you use a queue. For the actual shortest path algo, you need a map from node to previous node, which lets you recover the path when you hit the target. (In a language with real CONS lists, you'd just reverse the list when you hit the target which would be exactly the same as the DFS.) So I'd argue that the difference in difficulty is trivial, and OP would be well-served by surmounting it.

Comment: @rici yes. The difference is that I was trying to answer OP's question, and you're trying to push them to learn new and useful things.

Comment: @redtuna: My first thought was, "Sure, guilty as charged. Give a man a fish...". But, really, there is no basis to assume that BFS is a "new thing" and DFS is not. The OP is looking to learn a new thing, either way, so they might as well learn the better one for this problem. But to be clearer about my motivations, it's not just the OP who I'm trying to "push to learn new and useful things."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Calumn: DFS is the simplest approach here. Here is a simple solution in python-like pseudocode. It will print the solution as a sequence of 'L','R',U','D' to indicate left,right,up, or down.

```
def flood(x,y,story):
  if (visited[x][y] or map[x][y]=='0'): return;
  visited[x][y]=True;
  if (map[x][y]=='3'): 
    print 'done. The path is: '+story
    return
  if (x<len(a[0])): flood(x+1,y,story+'R')
  if (y<len(a)): flood(x,y+1,story+'D')
  if (x>0): flood(x-1,y,story+'L')
  if (y>0): flood(x,y-1,story+'U')

def solve(map):
  visited = array_of_false_of_same_size_as(map)
  x,y = find_the_two(map)
  flood(x,y,'')
```

The optimization of making it stop as soon as it finds a solution is left as an exercise to the reader (you could make flood return a boolean to indicate if it found something, or use a global flag).

*(p.s. I made this answer community wiki since I'm just clarifying Calumn's answer. I can't claim much credit)*

#### Breadth-First Search version, also in Python

For what it's worth, and just to show that breadth-first search is not that complicated, an actual runnable program in Python:

```
def find(grid, xstart=0, ystart=0):
  # Maps (xi,yi) to (x(i-1), y(i-1))
  prev = {(xstart, ystart):None}

  # Prepare for the breadth-first search
  queue = [(xstart, ystart)]
  qpos = 0
  # Possibly enqueue a trial coordinate
  def enqueue(prevxy, dx, dy):
    x = prevxy[0] + dx
    y = prevxy[1] + dy
    xy = (x, y)
    # Check that it hasn't been visited and the coordinates
    # are valid and the grid position is not a 0
    if (xy not in prev
        and x >= 0 and x < len(grid)
        and y >= 0 and y < len(grid[x])
        and grid[x][y] != 0):
      # Record the history (and the fact that we've been here)
      prev[xy] = prevxy
      # If we found the target, signal success
      if grid[x][y] == 3:
        return xy
      # Otherwise, queue the new coordinates
      else:
        queue.append(xy)
        return None

  # The actual breadth-first search
  while qpos < len(queue):
    xy = queue[qpos]
    qpos += 1
    found = (  enqueue(xy, 1, 0)
            or enqueue(xy, 0, 1)
            or enqueue(xy, -1, 0)
            or enqueue(xy, 0, -1))
    if found: break

  # Recover the path
  path = []
  while found:
    path.append(found)
    found = prev[found]
  path.reverse()
  return path

# Test run    
grid = [ [2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
       , [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
       , [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
       , [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]
       , [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1]
       , [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,3]
       ]
for x, y in find(grid): grid[x][y]='*'
print '\n'.join(''.join(str(p) for p in line) for line in grid)
```

Output:

```
*******1100000
000000*1000000
000011******11
00001111100*11
00001110000*01
00001111100***
```

Comment: does this solution avoid "loop"? For example if a path is straight down with width 2, would this algorithm walk all the way down first and then walk right one step, then all the way up ?

Comment: This is a solution, yes. If there is a path from "2" to "3", it will find it. Is uses the "visited" datastructure to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: This algo also won't track back in the example you're given, even though the original question did not specify that requirement.

Comment: sry, edited my question and added that requirement in

Comment: For the new question I recommend using BFS instead of DFS. This gets you a shortest path, guaranteeing no "wasted walk".